# Cannot create a boxplot from a CSV file in Python with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, matplotlib

I cannot create a full boxplot from my CSV file with `pandas` and `matplotlib` in Python.

This is what I get:

[image]

My CSV file:

```
id,type_EN,nb_EN
1,VP,15
2,VN,600
3,FP,78
4,FN,17
5,NOK,974
```

My code:

```
# import the required library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


# load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("boxplot.csv")

# display 5 rows of dataset
# df.head()

# print the boxplot
df.boxplot(by ="type_EN", column =["nb_EN"], grid = False)
```

Comment: I realised that my plot is correct - I guess I couldn't generate a traditional box plot because I don't have multiple values per type (and therefore, `pandas` couldn't calculate the median value and other metrics). So my boxplots are only the strikes corresponding to single values.